# How to compare field with multi selection and array in meta query in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, elementor, meta-query

I have a field that contains a few values from select box with multi selection. I need to get some customers that have the same categories.

So I have this array of categories id's.

*It's an acf field that contains taxnomey of custom categories and its a multi select.*

```
array('1360','1239','1267')
```

I want to select all the customers that have one or two from those categories. I try to do this:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [key] => form_to
                [value] => 1
                [compare] => LIKE
            )

        [relation] => AND
        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [relation] => OR
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [key] => cats
                                [value] => 1360
                                [compare] => LIKE
                            )

                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [relation] => OR
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [key] => cats
                                [value] => 1239
                                [compare] => LIKE
                            )

                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [relation] => OR
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [key] => cats
                                [value] => 1267
                                [compare] => LIKE
                            )

                    )

            )

    )

)
```

But it doesnt work, what can I do?

Comment: What do you mean by: "I want to select all the customers that have one or two from those categories."

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're looking for `array_diff` https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php but I don't enouth info.

Comment: The customer choose several categories, and I want to select those customer that choose at least one from the categories

Comment: Still where is that saved? How is that saved? You need to complete your question

Comment: i've update the question

Comment: Which are the "rules" for this acf field, where is it set to save/display?